# C# Cosmos DB ReadItemAsync Partition Key multiple values

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have a container that has a partition key made up of two fields. Neither of them is 'id'. In this example it is FormId and Version.

I am calling a function that uses ReadItemAsync to return a single document from the container. I'd like to include the Partition Key parameter as the data in the container is set to get very large and I'd rather not have the query run cross partition based solely on the id value. However, when I make the call I can't figure out how to structure the Partition Key value.

```
    public async Task<dynamic> GetItemAsync(string id, string? partitionId, string containerName)
    {
        try
        {
            Container container = _client.GetContainer(_databaseName, containerName);
            ItemResponse<dynamic> response;
    
            if (partitionId == null)
                response = await container.ReadItemAsync<dynamic>(id, PartitionKey.None);
            else
                response = await container.ReadItemAsync<dynamic>(id, new PartitionKey(partitionId));
    
            return response.Resource;
        }
        catch (CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I call with the function with the id Guid and null as the partition key, the function works fine. When I pass in a string representing the Partition Key in any of the following ways I get no data found:

```
    formId + "." + version
    formId + "/" + version
    formId + "\\" + version
```

How should the partition key parameter be structured when it is made up of more than one field?

Edit 1: Example of the document instance:

```
    {
        "formID": "e8493c8b-6736-4360-b781-5d94e93fe545",
        "version": "1",
        "id": "71d7458d-b71c-467e-b5b9-2b646dbd5435",
        "_rid": "QMgvAKsrCcABAAAAAAAAAA==",
        "_self": "dbs/QMgvAA==/colls/QMgvAKsrCcA=/docs/QMgvAKsrCcABAAAAAAAAAA==/",
        "_etag": "\"5f019a17-0000-1100-0000-6205202f0000\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1644503087
    }
```

The Partition Key is set as \formId.version.

Comment: is there a document in the container your calling with same id and pk your sending in the functions?

Comment: Can you share an example of a document that exists (taken maybe from Data Explorer, trim any extra information outside of the id and partition key) that you cannot find with ReadItem, which is the container's Partition Key Definition (`/?????`) and how are you calling the ReadItem (what are the parameter values)

Comment: @AmjadS. Yes I've made sure the details in the document align with my search. It only contains one test document at the moment.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I've added the instance example and what the partition is set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments and the new information, the problem is casing on the attribute name.

`/formId.version` as Partition key definition means your documents should have this format:

```
{
    "formId": {
        "version": "some value"
    },
    "id": "the id"
}
```

The "dot" is saying that `formId` is actually an object and inside there should be a `version` property.

To read such a document, you would do:

`container.ReadItem<dynamic>("the id", new PartitionKey("some value"))`

The document example you provide has `formID` which means it really has no Partition Key value. Furthermore, the other problem is, even if the casing matched, you are using a string value, not a nested JSON object with a `version` property.

It seems that you would need to have `/formID` as the Partition Key Definition to fit the code and document you are sharing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it has made things a lot clearer. I thought you could have multiple values from the document as your Partition Key. I realise now you can only pick one, so I created a new field that combines formId and Version and have made that the PK and it is now working as I want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped, please mark the answer so it helps others. What you did (combining fields into 1 value as PK) is called [Synthetic Partition Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/synthetic-partition-keys)